# How to get TableAdapters to properly run an insert and then a SELECT_LAST_ID()

Tags: c#, mysql, tableadapter

Sniplet:

```
    int resNo = -1;
    MoviesTableAdapters.reservationTableAdapter resAdapter = new MoviesTableAdapters.reservationTableAdapter();
    if (Int32.TryParse(info[1], out phoneNo))
    {
    resNo = resAdapter.InsertQuery(phoneNo, info[0]);
    }
```

Running this I keep getting 1 as a return, even though my LAST_INSERT_ID() is something different.

My query is like this

```
INSERT INTO `reservation` (`phone_no`, `password`) VALUES (@phone_no, @password);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM reservation;
```

The obvious conclusion here is that the return of the integer didn't work, but no matter what I initialize resNo to, I still get 1 - when I run it in my website, when I run it directly against the MySQL database I get the correct ID.

This has lead me to the conclusion, that it is either me who're using the TableAdapter wrong/misunderstood how it works.

Thanks in advance for any answers.

Answer (score -1):

Here's what I think not 100% sure.

**Why does it not work in the website**
In your website each new query gets to use a new connection.

`last_insert_id()` only returns the last_id of the **current** connection.
Since query1: `insert ...` uses a different connection from query2: `select last_insert_id()` query2 will always return 1.

**And why does it work ok in the database**
Running directly against the database, the database is clever enough to keep the same connection open and query1 and query2 run in the same connection.

**What to do about it**
You need to research how to force your c# code to use persistent connections.